# CSV File Editor

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I need to create a CSV File editor. The user should be able to upload a CSV file, and the data should automatically be loaded into a text area. I have seen many examples of CSV data being transferred from a text area to, for example, a table, but I can't find something that will help me with actually uploading a file, reading the data from it in to a 2D array, and then placing it in a text area.

I can transfer the data into an editable table from the text area without problem.

So the question is: How can I upload a file, read the data from it (and keep the format of the CSV) and display the correct format in a text area element?

I am not currently concerned about checking to see if the CSV is correct etc etc. I just need to know how to handle the data. Sorry, but my Ajax knowledge is very limited. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with C# syntax? If so, [this article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c) might give you some ideas. It presents a CSV editor for the desktop. Just upload the file like any other file and use the same techniques for processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading it is no different than how any other form works in HTML.

You can use a file input to select a file, then upload it as part of the form data (it's automatic) or supply the user with a textarea to paste into. Submitting the form will "upload" the data to the server. You don't need AJAX to do any of this, but it is an option.

What you do with the data on the server is up to you.

Comment: Physically uploading the file is not the problem. I need to open the file, read the contents, and send the contents back to the HTML text area in the CSV format that is was uploaded.

Comment: Then you need to select a server-side language to process this form data.